# Access protected property WC_Product_Variation::$id in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I have this error logs related to this line of code:

```
$product->id = $product->variation_id;
```

The error log is:

> (fatal error) Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property WC_Product_Variation::$id in ....:857
>
> Stack trace: (Object(WC_Product_Variation) 881
>
> 881: $variation = $this->convert_variation_product_prices($variation, $currency);
>
> Stack trace: load_variation_in_currency (811)
>
> 811: $variation = $this->load_variation_in_currency($variation_id, $currency);
>
> Stack trace: convert_variable_product_prices(Object(WC_Product_Variable) 767
>
> 767: $product = $object->$method($product, $currency);

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**You need to replace** the incorrect guilty line: `$product->id = $product->variation_id;` by the following *(as `$product` is a `WC_Product_Variation`)*:

```
$product_id = $product->get_id();
```

or

```
$variation_id = $product->get_id();
```

Where `$product_id` *(or `$variation_id`)* is the variable to be used in your code.

> Since Woocommerce 3 and [CRUD Objects](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) `WC_Product` properties can't be accessed directly and you should use [available getters methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) instead.
>
> So <strike>`$product->id`</strike> needs to be changed to **`$product->get_id()`**

To get the parent variable product ID you will use

```
$parent_product_id = $product->get_parent_id();
```

Comment: Dear LoicTheAztec, thanks for the help. Can you please explain more about: Since Woocommerce 3 and CRUD Objects WC_Product properties can't be accessed directly and you should use available getters methods instead.

So $product->id needs to be changed to $product->get_id() 

To get the parent variable product ID you will use

$parent_product_id = $product->get_parent_id();

Comment: Which line and code i need to replace at: abstract-wc-product.php

Comment: @user10840816 abstract-wc-product.php is a woocommerce core file: NEVER touch to Woocommerce core files. Is prohibited to edit or change any Wordpress, Woocommerce or any other plugin source code. Your question doesn't give any details related to the location where this problem occurs. My answer just answers your question explaining, but it will not solve it. It seems that something is outdated and needs to be updated.